# Cannot Check a Check-box with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried to crawl a website and need to check some checkboxes.

```
xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath

for i in range(20):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    try:
        xpath("//*[@id='pub_check_sort3_0']").click()
        # checkbox = xpath("//*[@id='pub_check_sort3_0']")
        # driver.execute("arguments[0].click();",checkbox)
        break
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print('retry')
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        raise e
```

Those are the codes that I tried to click a check-box and still cannot click the check-box. Also, I tried not only xpath value, tried with id and class.

```
<li class="general">
  <span class="fCheck">
    <input onclick="checkAction(this)" class="selectPL" type="checkbox" id="pub_check_sort3_0" value="025001">
     <label for="pub_check_sort3_0"></label>Academic Journal (1,505)</span></li>
```

Those are HTML codes for the check-box and following is the xpath
    //*[@id="pub_check_sort3_0"]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chanhee.kang/Desktop/DBpia/db_sel.py", line 37, in     <module>
    xpath("//*[@id='pub_check_sort3_0']").click()
  File "/Users/chanhee.kang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/chanhee.kang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in     _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/chanhee.kang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/chanhee.kang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in     check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:     Message: element click intercepted: Element <input     onclick="checkAction(this)" class="selectPL" type="checkbox"     id="pub_check_sort3_0" value="025001"> is not clickable at point (73,     555). Other element would receive the click: <div class="filterGroup     eToggleSection">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6     (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64)
```

Those are the errors that I got.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.general label[for='pub_check_sort3_0']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='general']//label[@for='pub_check_sort3_0']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```